# What does it actually mean by Task Planning?

Tags: first-robotics, planning

According to the research paper [Parallel process decomposition of a dynamic manipulation task: robotic sewing (D. Gershon, DOI: 10.1109/70.56654)](https://www.scribd.com/document/411905819/1990-Parallel-process-decomposition-of-a-dynamic-manipulation-task-robotic-sewing):

> Abstract - ... **The task planner approach, as promoted by  the Al community,  is  unsuited  to tasks  involving  interaction with  a  dynamic  environment.**  ....
>   ... ... ...
>   Task  planning  is  essentially  an  off-line  activity,  based 
>   on  a  "snap-shot"  of the  world,  and  is  therefore  incompati-
>   ble  with  dynamic  tasks  and  environments.  Task  planners  re-
>   quire  a  single model  of the world,  whereas  different models 
>   may  be  appropriate  for  different  objectives,  e.g.,  an  octree 
>   representation  is  efficient  for  obstacle  avoidance,  whereas  a 
>   RAPT-style model  [36]  is  better suited to  planning  compliant 
>   motion  tasks.  Attempts  to develop  experimental  task planner 
>   systems  revealed  additional difficulties,  such as  image  under-
>   standing,  sensor  fusion,  error  recovery,  and  the  potential  for 
>   catastrophic  failures  [29]....
>   ..... ..... ....
>
> Many control  schemes,  such  as  **adaptive  control**  [15],  [27]  and 
>   sliding-mode control  [41],  can  accommodate bounded uncertainties  in  the model of  the controlled system. However,  these controllers are  not generally  robust  to  disturbances generated by  a dynamic  interacting  environment.

Now, [Multi-arm robot control system for manipulation of flexible materials in sewing operation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957415899000471) seems to be implementing a multi-arm robot system on the basis of "Task Planning" approach. And, [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326900951_Flexible_Garment_Handling_with_Adaptive_Control_Strategies) implemented a robot system using adaptive control.

So, what is the catch here? Why does the 1st article say that use of task planning and adaptive control aren't possible in case of dynamic tasks?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user366312, but I'm afraid it's not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you don't understand with it. Take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are seeing here is a decade advancement in microprocessor and robotic control technologies.

By the time the second and third papers were written, in 2000 & 1998, the definition of 'task planning' had switched from static pre-planning to dynamic reactive planning.

The difference in microcomputer speeds between 1990 and 1998 is enormous. In 1990 typical CPUs included the 80486 & i860. They were clocked at double digit MHz, and didn't have the power to do the complex floating point operations required for doing task planning in real time.

By the late 90's microprocessors were significantly faster, GHz chips were going into production and CPUs were doing more per cycle. Significantly, SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data) pipelines like SSE were being implemented so the big matrix manipulations needed to do dynamic task planning were starting to become efficient enough to use in near real time.

This all made enough difference that suddenly things which were inconceivable at the start of the decade were now viable.